# wpf chart show horizontal scroll bar/viewer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, scroll, charts

I have a wpf column series chart and I have more than 15 columns. I want the horizontal scroll to show up. And i am not able to.

Any help.

Comment: WPF doesn't have a native chart control.  Document what you used.

Comment: Can you provide more information or follow up if you found a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you nest your chart into a ScrollViewer:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto>
    <YourChartHere />
</ScrollViewer>
```